# $\omega_1-$tree with $\omega_2$ branches of length $\omega_1$

Tags: set-theory

Let's assume there's a family $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\omega_1)$ such that $$\forall\alpha\in\omega_1\ |\{A\cap\alpha:\ A\in\mathcal{A}\}|\leq\omega$$ $$\forall X\in[\omega_1]^{\omega_1}\ \exists A\in\mathcal{A}\ (|A|=\omega_1\ \wedge\ A\subseteq X)$$
Based on that the problem is to prove there exists an $\omega_1-$tree $T$ which has at least $\omega_2$ branches of length $\omega_1$.

Ok, so what I thought of is to make a tree with the inclusion ordering which has $A\cap\alpha$ on level $\alpha$. It seems as the only reasonable idea. But then... What if the sets in $\mathcal{A}$ have large "holes" in that they yield the same set for some $\alpha$'s and $\alpha +1$'s, i.e. $A\cap\alpha=A\cap(\alpha + 1)$. Then there might not be any branches of length $2^{\omega_1}$, and this is what I need.

I don't have any ideas... This is frustrating, I've been thinking about this for the past few hours to no avail so far. Is it simple to notice how this tree should look like?

Comment: You define a tree of height $\omega_1$ and levels of size $\omega$. The nodes at height $\alpha$ are labelled by the sets $A\cap\alpha$ for $A\in\mathcal{A}$, and the ordering is defined accordingly. The point is that, even if $A\cap(\alpha+1)=A\cap\alpha$, you have distinct nodes, one for the $\alpha$-th level, and one for the $(\alpha+1)$-st. If this coincidence bothers you, then instead set the levels at level $\alpha$ to be ordered pairs $(\alpha,A\cap\alpha)$.

Comment: (I believe you do not mean $2^{\omega_1}$ either time it appears in your post.)

Comment: Oh, I don't? I thought if I want at least $\omega_2$ branches that means at least $2^{\omega_1}$. Since $2^{\omega_1}\geq\omega_2$

Comment: @Jules: No, it's the other way round: $\omega_2\le 2^{\omega_1}$.

Comment: And yes, distinct nodes are a cool thing to have :) But the inclusion ordering is not a good idea, is that what you mean?

Comment: @Brian That's what I wrote :)

Comment: @Jules: But you're misunderstanding it. You can have $\omega_2$ without having $2^{\omega_1}$, because $\omega_2$ can be smaller.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I just thought it's "simple" to find $2^{\omega_1}$ branches which woould automatically give me "at least $\omega_2$" branches. This is because all the subsets of cardinality $\omega_1$ are mentioned in the problem, I assumed it had something to do with that. And if it doesn't, then it's even more unclear where this $\omega_2$ comes from.

Comment: Anyway, your use of $2^{\omega_1}$ really makes no sense in what you wrote. You cannot have branches of length $2^{\omega_1}$, for instance. Your index $n$ being some ordinal less than $2^{\omega_1}$ is also incorrect. This has nothing to do with whether you get $2^{\aleph_1}$ or only $\aleph_2$ branches at the end.

Comment: Oh boy, that index is stupid, correct. But is the overall idea ok? To have $A\cap\alpha$ as the nodes and something different from the inclusion as the ordering?